# Как правильно реализовать цикличность вопроса?

Tags: java

Как правильно реализовать цикл, когда при неправильном ответе программа стартует заново, пока не будет получен верный ответ?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Education {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int randomValue = 1 + (int) (Math.random() * 10); // Рандомит число от 1 о 10
        System.out.println("(" + randomValue + ") - подсказка"); // Подсказка (для теста)
        System.out.println("Угадай число от 1 до 10");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int scanResult = scanner.nextInt();

        while (randomValue == scanResult){
            System.out.println("Верно");
            break;
            if (randomValue != scanResult){
                System.out.println("Не верно, попробуй еще раз");
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Скорее всего вам нужен следующий цикл

```
while (true){   
    if (randomValue == scanResult){
        System.out.println("Верно");
        break;
    }
    System.out.println("Не верно, попробуй еще раз");
    scanResult = scanner.nextInt();
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, реализовал по вашему примеру, только использую цикл for

Comment: только в условие while нужен true